# WordPress Post Meda data

Tags: php, wordpress

Good afternoon,

I'm having a bit of trouble to remove the following text: **By** and the brackets before the author's name and the bracket after the date. As in the screenshot below, I already removed the author's name and category.

[Screenshot of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NhjJ.png)

Looking forward to hearing the feedback

Comment: This may be in your page.php or any other custom post php in the theme, but it also may be in a written hook, you give us very little information to go from.

Comment: Hi Darvalla, Thank you for getting back to me and sorry about that. I created a "blog" page with a module that pulls in the recent blog posts. and in this module, I have the problem. I'm using Divi builder as a page builder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, I can't say any more than that you have to look into the plugin it's PHP files. Please provide us more information, yo we can understand your issue way better. **Furthermore, you can also hide your object with pure CSS:**

```
<div class="button"></div>

.button {
  display:none;
}
```

Have a look into this: https://www.lifewire.com/display-none-vs-visibility-hidden-3466884

Answer (score 0):

Just go to single.php in your theme and comment out the code there. OR use "Inspect" in browser and add  proper styling (display:none) to the class of the corresponding `div`.

Still stuck, just put the name of the theme you are using.